# Why does the visa for India for ask for the name of my father/husband?

Tags: visas, india, paperwork, discrimination

The [visa form](http://www.cdc.gov/globalhealth/visa/pdf/india.pdf) for US residents specifically asks for the name of my husband or father:

[image: detail from visa form]

Other countries (e.g. [France](http://www.vfs-in-fr.com/pdf/Notice%20_d%27utilisation.pdf)) ask for detailed information about both of my parents.

Why does the US form ask for "father or husband"?

Comment: India has a [bewildering variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_name) (by US or UK standards) of personal naming conventions, varying by region and language, but many use their father's given name as a middle name, and many married women do the same with their husband's given name. No doubt the MEA has a standard filing system which uses these data points (plus criteria indicated elsewhere, e.g. birthplace), and asks the same information from foreigners so that they can be organized according to the same system. As to why the French version is different, you'll need to ask the ministry.

Comment: The Indian visa form also asks for your mother's name.

Comment: I think you looked at the first page only. The first question on the second page of the form you linked to is `Name and nationality of mother`.

Comment: @nikhil500 it'd be worth putting that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why India asks for it - but I do know that in some countries the name of the *guardian* (either the husband for women or father for males and unmarried girls) is part of your passport identification page.

This is checked when you are traveling - for example, if I am to sponsor my wife's visa, her passport must state my name under "Father/Husband", otherwise the application is not approved.

It might be something similar in India.

@choster's guess about the name is also a good possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite common in some Asia countries. For example here in Thailand it is the same, even though my parents are now long dead I have to list them on various forms.

In the case of India I think they love bureaucracy, it is an old habit and keeps lots of people in jobs I guess. Blame it on the Brits I suppose, though overall I think they helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you looked at the first page only. The first question on the second page of the form you linked to is `Name and nationality of mother`.

Comment: There are several different versions of this form available online, and not all of them ask about the nationality of the mother.